# Why can't I write $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>5)$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I have a confusion with the memorylessness property of **Exponential** distribution.

If exponential distribution is memoryless (i.e. the past has no bearing on its future behavior), why can't I write $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>5)$?

If

- $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>4)$
- $P(X>5|X>2) = P(X>3)$
- $P(X>5|X>3) = P(X>2)$
  ...

past **definitely** has an effect on present.

Can anyone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: The memoryless property of the exponential distribution is that $X\sim \exp(\lambda)$ has $P(X > s + t\,|\, X > t)$ independent of $t$. The expression in the titel is $P(X > 4)$, not $P(X > 5)$. (The latter would imply that $X > 1$ almost surely.)

Comment: Memoryless means $\Bbb P(X > m+n \mid X>m ) = \Bbb P(X> n).$ So in your case $\Bbb P(X>5 \mid X>1) = \Bbb P(X>4).$

Comment: @Dbchatto67, so, it is not actually memoryless in true sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "actually memoryless"?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 *the past has no bearing on its future behavior* doesn't hold. Coz, If $P(X>5|X>2) = P(X>3)$ which means past has an effect on present.

Comment: What is past in the event $(X>m+n \mid X>m)$?

Comment: @Dbchatto67, $X>m$.

Comment: Memoryless property means waiting time until a certain event, does not depend on how much time has elapsed already

Comment: @user366312 what you're thinking of is independence not memorylessness.

Comment: Turn things around: first learn that rv $X$ with exponential distribution has the property $P(X>s+t\mid X>t)=P(X>s)$. Then take knowledge of the fact that this property is what they call the "memoryless property". Then try to get hold on the question "why do they give this property that name?". The last question is legal and is IMV a better one than the one posed in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on $P(X>5\mid X>3)=P(X>2)$ you conclude that the past has effect on the present. That is not true in this context.

Maybe a bell will ring if you rewrite this as:$$P(X-3>2\mid X-3>0)=P(X>2)$$

Yes, we have been waiting for the train now for $3$ minutes (condition $X>3)$ but apparantly under that condition the time that we still have to wait *is equipped with the same distribution* as it was at the moment we arrived at the station. The $3$ minutes of waiting apparantly did not change that distribution: the past did not have an effect on the present.